# Position number is negative

Tags: sketch-app

As you can see in the picture, I'm selecting the "Ads" object, it is at the top of the screen, but the position is (0,-82).

If I change by manual, mean I change -82 to 0, the "Ads"object will move down by 82 pixel, which is wrong.

How I can set my position number to normal ( which is 0,0)?

Thank you fro your help
[image: Negative position number]

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is actually correct. In software like Sketch, Photoshop, and Illustrator (0,0) is considered to be the top left corner of your canvas or artboard, and anything positioned above or to the left of that goes into negative values.

If you turn on your rulers (View > Canvas > Show Rulers) it might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's causing this is that you've accidentally changed the ruler's point of origin. (I find that this happens quite easily when adding smart guides.) To solve this, turn on your rulers, as suggested above, (View > Canvas > Show Rulers) and double-click the empty square in the top left corner of the canvas. (See image.)[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Johannes, it works for me and help my developers a lot because they need a correct numbers to implement the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug in Sketch, try to reload it.
Positions of shapes inside artboards are calculated from top left corner of the artboard not canvas.

Also, there is a good practice to start your design workflow from positioning your first artboard at (0, 0).